# Changing image src onClick with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this HTML on my site: 
`<a href="#1" id="slick-toggle"><img src="img1.jpg"/></a>`

When I click this link, I would like to change the image src to `img2.jpg`. And revert back to `img1.jpg` when clicked again & so on. **Can someone explain how I do this using jQuery?**

Here is my existing **jQuery** if this helps:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
  $('#slick-toggle').click(function() {
    $('#slickbox').toggle(400);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Many thanks for any pointers with this :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
  $('#slick-toggle').click(function() {
    $('img', this).attr('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
        return oldSrc == 'img1.jpg' ? 'img2.jpg' : 'img1.jpg';
    });
    $('#slickbox').toggle(400);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: never knew you could pass a `function` as the second parameter for jQuery, amazing

Comment: Only slight problem here is @thecodeparadox is that after the initial switch, it doesn't switch back again. So it goes from `img1` to `img2` and then doesn't go back to `img` again. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, must have been a typo. Works now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the image inside since your click handler is on the  that wraps it, like this:

```
$('a#slick-toggle').click(function() {
  var img = $('#share')[0], isSwap = "True";
  img.src = isSwap ? img.src.replace("_img1","_img2") : img.src.replace("_img2","_img1");
  $('.img-swap').toggleClass("on");
  $('#atBox').toggle(100);
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function for this:

```
$('#mylink').toggle(
     function(){
          $(this).attr('src','img2.jpg');
     },
     function(){
          $(this).attr('src','img3.jpg');
     }
// and so on..
);
```

you can add more function in it...