# Jquery switch between 2 images not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I've tried many different blocks of code, but I cannot get this to work. I'm trying to do something very simple-switch between 2 images onclick. I tried many solutions on this forum to no avail. Is it different when the page is within an iframe? Could there be a path issue to the images?

Heres my code:

**JS**

```
$("#infoToggler img").click(function() {
    window.alert('hi');
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="infoToggler"> 
    <img src="bkramer1.jpg" />
    <img src="bkramer2.jpg" style="display:none"/>          
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have to say `.find('img')` again.

Comment: Since you assigning `.click` to `img` here so `$(this)` gets you `img` itself. Why `find('img')` then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is working sample

```
$("#infoToggler img").click(function() {
   $("#infoToggler img").toggle(); //you need to toggle images both
});
```

and a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/baximilian/5wYha/)

Comment: this one's woring. I must have had my script in the wrong place. Thanks to everyones input!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `$("#infoToggler img")`, which selects all images inside element with id `#infoToggler`.

So no need to find `img` again.

You are getting it wrong way, try this way:

```
$("#infoToggler img").click(function() {
    window.alert('hi');
    $("#infoToggler img").toggle();
});
```

Yes, you will have to toggle both.

Look here, gives you an example : http://jsfiddle.net/mz47F/

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem if you're willing to change your jquery function to "ready" instead of "click"

[Changing image src onClick with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894815/changing-image-src-onclick-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Apply your click event to your wrapper, then toggle the visibility of the images like so.

```
$("#infoToggler").click(function() {
   $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working example that you can toggle between two images.

http://jsfiddle.net/6WQTz/

```
$("#infoToggler img").click(function() {
  $('img:first').toggle();
  $('img:last').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Because your code will toggle the first and last image on the page.  This does not help the OP

Comment: @KennyThompson It's true, because Matt has his code structured that way.

Comment: While the code he posted only displays one div wrapping two images, it would not be wise to assume that is the only html on the page.

Comment: It wouldn't be wise to assume there maybe additional DOM element inside the wrapper either. Let's leave that to the person who asks the question.

Comment: I am not trying to be offensive. I am just pointing out your selectors within the click event will be applied to every `img` tag on the page, not just within the `#infoToggler` div.

Comment: yes there is other html on the page but only 2 img in the div no other elements

Comment: Ok, I'm not even getting the alert. So I think the main issue is clicking the div is not working. I tried putting the script in different parts of the page but its not making any difference.

Comment: putting the inline onclick inside the div works. I can get an alert window as well as swap image, but I don't think you can switch back to the original image inline.